# Cascade delete with kubernetes master-API

Tags: kubernetes

In the kubectl tool there is the option:

```
--cascade[=true]: If true, cascade the deletion of the resources managed by this resource (e.g. Pods created by a ReplicationController).  Default true.
```

But when I'm doing the 'delete' using the API(1.2) by default the deleted resources doesn't cascade.

Is there a simple way to do it with the api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, cascading delete is client side only. There are plans to move that logic server side in future versions

Comment: Do you have the issue #?